# .NET Core - EF - trying to "OR" built up Where's in a for loop

Tags: asp.net-core, entity, where-clause

**I try to filter data using multiple Where**, built up in a loop. **They must be chained with a OR**

I read I should use **PredicateBuilder** from this page ttp://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

problem : *it does not return any data*

I managed to debug the final query and noticed

- the OR clauses are not present
- a strange CAST line was present (which when I remove it, data appear)

here is the part that adds to the IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<Lead> data = context.Leads.AsQueryable();

List<ZipCodeRange> ranges = Tools.CreateZipCodesRanges();

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuItem>>(leadsSearch.searchByZipcodes);

var activeRanges = items
    .Where(item=>item.active)
    .Select(item => ranges[item.id])
    .ToList();

data = data.Where(d => activeRanges.Any(range => range.Min <= d.Company.ZipCodeNum &&
                                                range.Max >= d.Company.ZipCodeNum));

var leads = await data.ToListAsync();
```

here is how I generate the ranges :

```
public static List<ZipCodeRange> CreateZipCodesRanges()
{
    List<ZipCodeRange> zipCodeRanges = new List<ZipCodeRange>();

    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 1000, Max = 1495 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 4000, Max = 7999 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 1500, Max = 1999 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 2000, Max = 2699 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 2800, Max = 2999 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 3000, Max = 3499 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 3500, Max = 3999 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 8000, Max = 8999 });
    zipCodeRanges.Add(new ZipCodeRange() { Min = 9000, Max = 9999 });

    return zipCodeRanges;
}
```

here is the generated query:

```
SELECT [l].[Id], [l].[AdminNotes], [l].[CompanyId], [l].[ContactId], [l].[CreationDate], [l].[CreationUserId], [l].[FacialValue], [l].[FedEce], [l].[FirstOrderDate], [l].[Identifier], [l].[LastOrderDate], [l].[Locked], [l].[ModificationDate], [l].[ModificationUserId], [l].[Notes], [l].[PartnerId], [l].[PrestationPercent], [l].[Products], [l].[Status], [l].[TicketsPerDay], [l].[ToTreat], [c].[Id], [c].[BceNumber], [c].[Box], [c].[City], [c].[Country], [c].[Name], [c].[Number], [c].[Size], [c].[Street], [c].[ZipCode], [c].[ZipCodeNum], [c0].[Id], [c0].[Civility], [c0].[CreationDate], [c0].[CreationUserId], [c0].[Email], [c0].[FirstName], [c0].[Language], [c0].[LastName], [c0].[Mobile], [c0].[ModificationDate], [c0].[ModificationUserId], [c0].[Phone], [c0].[Position], [c0].[Type]
FROM [leads] AS [l]
INNER JOIN [companies] AS [c] ON [l].[CompanyId] = [c].[Id]
INNER JOIN [contacts] AS [c0] ON [l].[ContactId] = [c0].[Id]
WHERE CAST(0 AS bit) = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

what am I doing wrong ?

thanks for your help

[edit]

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Lead>
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<Company>, 
        inner: l => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(l, "CompanyId"), 
        outerKeySelector: c => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Lead, Company>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(l => __activeRanges_0
        .Any(range => (Nullable<int>)range.Min <= l.Inner.ZipCodeNum && (Nullable<int>)range.Max >= l.Inner.ZipCodeNum))' could not be translated.
```

Comment: Hi @phil123456, Please check your code in the foreach statement, you are filtering the data based on the `range` variable, instead of the `item` property, so it might cause the where clause using wrong condition.

Comment: indeed, I updated my code, but I still get the same sort of error, (I updated the code above and the error)

Comment: Try to set a break point to check whether the activeRanges contains correct values. It seems that it contains the null values. Besides, according to the existing code, I have create a sample on my machine, it seems that everything works well. So, can you post the related classes, such as Lead, Company, MenuItem, and add some test data (for the `items` and `activeRanges` ) to create a simple sample to reproduce the problem, it can help us to reproduce the problem and help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without using PredicateBuilder by simply doing

```
var data = context.Leads
                  .Where(lead => items.Any(item => item.Min <= lead.Company.ZipCodeNum && 
                                                   item.Max >= lead.Company.ZipCodeNum))
```

**Edit**

For your updated code in the screenshot just remove the foreach at all and replace it with

```
var activeRanges = items
                     .Where(item.active)
                     .Select(item => ranges[item.id])
                     .ToList();

data = data.Where(d => activeRanges.Any(range=> range.Min <= d.Company.ZipCodeNum && 
                                                range.Max >= d.Company.ZipCodeNum))
```

Comment: @phil123456 this is the OR operation you are looking for. The .Any() clause checks if at least one item in items matches the given criteria (which in this case contains an && but this is only the criteria which is applied for each single item) - therefore it works the same as joining OR operations for all items together

Comment: @phil123456 So what my code essentially does is returning all leads where the company's zip code number is between Min and Max of at least one item - isn't that what you were trying to get?

Comment: @phil123456 my code is doing exactly that for you - broadly speaking Any() does an internal for-loop checking the ranges for all items and returning true if the zip code is in at least one of this ranges. Please try out the code and check if it gives you the desired result.

Comment: @phil123456 I've update my answer to match your updated code

Comment: @phil It is not the same issue - what you are having now is a completley different problem. Your query is now correct but it just can't be translated to SQL because you are using the in memory object Range in your query. I cannot provide a solution for that as I don't know your complete code. But you must either do the filtering in memory by replacing AsQueryable() with ToList() or rewrite your query so it does not use in memory objects (whcih I cannot do for you because I dont know the logic behind the Range class etc.)

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: anyone can help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant get an answer, maybe EF is limited or something , so I did it this way:

```
List<int?> leadsIdsAll = new List<int?>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if(item.active)
    {
        ZipCodeRange range = ranges[item.id];

        List<int?> leadsIds = context.Leads.Where(l => range.Min <= l.Company.ZipCodeNum && range.Max >= l.Company.ZipCodeNum)
            .Select(l => l.Id).ToList();
        leadsIdsAll.AddRange(leadsIds);
    }
}

data = data.Where(l => leadsIdsAll.Contains(l.Id));
```